Chain rule for integrator function with Riemann-Stieltjes integral
I have a random variable $X$ with distribution function $F$. I am interested in evaluating the integral $$ \int g(x) \beta'(F(x)) F(dx) $$ where $\beta$ is smooth and monotone and $g$ is such that the integral exists. I would really like to say that
$$ \int g(x) \beta'(F(x)) F(dx) = \int g(x) d(\beta \circ F)(x).$$
This is true if, for example, $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, in which case it's just the chain rule applied to $\beta \circ F$. Is it true for more general variables $X$?
I think I have found a counterexample, but I am not sure about whether my calculations are accurate. I considered $\beta(x) = \exp(x)$ and $X$ to be a point mass at $0$, in which case I believe that the LHS of the equation above becomes $g(0)\exp(1)$ and the RHS becomes $g(0)[\exp(1) - 1]$. However, I am really not that comfortable with evaluating such integrals, so this could all be wrong.
I have tried to think about this in terms of Radon-Nikodym derivatives. I believe that this question becomes equivalent to asking what the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measure induced by $\beta \circ F$ is with respect to the measure induced by $F$. However, I wasn't able to get anywhere with this approach.
If anyone has any insight into this, it'd be much appreciated!

What is your definition of $F(dx)$? Stieltjes integrals involve $dF$, nof $F(dx)$.

I'm using the two interchangeably, similar to how people use $\mu(dx)$ and $d\mu(x)$ interchangeably. I've changed the notation to using $dF$.
